# JPA criteria query, No explicit selection and an implicit one cold not be determined

Tags: java, jpa

I want to do this query in JPA Criteria Query

```
select * from profile where deleteDate is null
```

So I was reading some tutorials and I did this Java code to do the query

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery();
Root profile = criteriaQuery.from(Profile.class);
criteriaQuery.where(builder.isNull(profile.get("deleteDate")));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Profile> result = query.getResultList();
```

But when I try to launch app It throws this message

```
No explicit selection and an implicit one cold not be determined
```

At now, property deleteDate is in a `abstract @MappedSuperclass` called `BaseEntity` and `Profile` extends from it

Comment: Did you try adding a select to the query? I.e. `query.select(profile)`

Comment: @Craig it works! thanks